Svelte5/SvelteKit2 - $page.data vs let data: LayoutData = $props() in page.svelte?
It appears to me, that the data set by the return of an outer (for example the global) layout.server.ts file is accessible in two ways by it's children and nested components:
// outer layout.server.ts
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async () => {
   return {
      myData: ["foo", "bar"]
   }
}


Version 1 through $page.data:
<script lang="ts">
   // version $page.data in +page.svelte
   import { page } from '$app/stores';
</script>

{$page.data}

and version 2 through $props():
<script lang="ts">
   // version $props() in +page.svelte
   import type { LayoutData } from './$types';
   let data: LayoutData = $props();
</script>

{data}

I am mainly interested in setting session data for the user and make it globally available in the whole application and all it's nested components without passing it from each server file. Just once in the global layout.server.ts and then every page and component nested inside can reach the passed data.
It appears to me, that on the client side both versions are accessing the same object, that is set on server side, as it's only set once there.
Is there a best practice / good reasons for doing one or the other version on client side? Or would it make sense to define a specific store for the session data (in my example myData: ["foo", "bar"])to make the code more readable / convenient imports / ...?
I'm only intersted in Svelte5 / SvelteKit2 answers or higher.

The page store is passed via context, so it is available in the entire component subtree, it is mainly there for convenience, so data does not need to be sent through props at every level. Since this is a store, it may also be less granular in its updates.
The data prop is only available in +layout & +page files, not regular components since it is passed directly to those by SvelteKit.
I generally prefer using the props where available and only use the store in regular components, especially deeply nested ones.

Hmmm, I cannot see the relation between $page.data and the context, you are referring to in the documentation. Note: I want to transfer session data from the server side to the client side. That means another client is not supposed to have access to the personal session data. It appears to me, that the only way to pass data from server to client is through $page.data, which is technically equal to $props()

That is the documentation for the Svelte context mechanism in general, of course you will not find any reference to $page.data which is a SvelteKit-specific thing. The fact that it uses a context internally is just an implementation detail. One of the reasons a context is used is exactly for client isolation: Each instance of the page has its own context so there is no danger of data being leaked between users.

OK - I really had a hard time getting this information out of the documentation. Thanks for clarifying.  That's a confidence booster.

Don't know if I'm doing it the best way, but here's what I do:

I have a file named logged-in-account.js, in which I export the writeable store loggedInAccount that contains null (default)
In my root layout.server.ts file I send back info about the account the user is logged in to
In my root +layout.svelte file I obtain that account (if it exists), and then I immediately put it in the loggedInAccount store exported from logged-in-account.js
In whichever file I need to access the logged in account, I just write $loggedInAccount

In VS Code, whenever I start writing $l, VS Code suggests to import loggedInAccount from the logged-in-account.js, so it's really convenient to use.
I have wondered if it would be better/more correct to use a context instead of a global store like this, but that suggestion I get from VS Code makes it so easy to use a global store, so I think I would stick to using the global store even if it's a bit incorrect/not optimal (I assume VS Code can't produce equally good suggestions and type safety when using getContext()).

So how do you distinguish between multiple users? What is each client sending to the server, so that client only gets its own data?
I'm using a session cookie for that purpose and extract it in hooks.server.ts. Here I put relevant session information into the locals variable, which is available in each server load function. As storage for the session data, I have a Redis cache - which takes the functionality of your logged-in-account.js file.
So passing data around on server-side seems done for me. I'm mainly curious on how to pass data to the client safely.

I use a signed HTTP only cookie created with cookie-signature to remember session information (the cookie stores the same information as in the loggedInAccount store, but in JSON format). Just as you, I have a server hook that populates locals with this information, so I also have access to it on the server.

Makes perfectly sense to me. Just to clarify: passing data from step 2 to 3 is through returning server load function and receiving through let page = $props()` on client side?
With regards to step 4: I had a store for this before refactoring to Svelte5 as well. I see the benefit of using IntelliSense in VS Code, but otherwise it appears to me, that stores now are less relevant: https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte/stores#When-to-use-stores . Maybe using a state-file instead of a store as in the example in the doc?

In the +layout.svelte file I use the data prop to read out the loggedInAccount. And I agree with you, if using a $state() works, then it's probably better to use that than a store. But I don't know if it will work. For example, If you need reactive values in context then you can pass a $state object into context, whose properties will be reactive.. This makes me all very unsure about when one can use $state() as a reactive variable, and when only the properties are reactive ^^'

Also note that if you use server-side rendering, then storing the loggedInAccount in a global variable/store/$state() might screw up that.

Yes - on the server side I'm pretty confident: all user specific information is in a Redis cache, where each user only can access the information, where the browser can present the secured cookie. As https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/brunnerh pointed out in a comment to his answer: saving information in $page.data is the safe place from SvelteKit using Svelte's context to put user specific information. So Bob cannot get to Alice's data.
